# I am trying to loop through a vector of objects and print each element of the objects

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, output

I am making an aircraft air control system. There is an aircraft object and there is a vector called "aircraftList_" which holds all the aircraft objects.
I am trying to write a method called "ListAllAircraft" which will print all the contents of aircraftList, could someone help?

Below are my first two guesses at it, neither worked

```
std::vector<Aircraft> ListAllAircraft(std::vector<Aircraft> aircraftList_)
{
    std::cout << aircraftList_;
}



std::vector<Aircraft> ListAllAircraft(std::vector<Aircraft> aircraftList_)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(aircraftList_); i++)
    {
        std::cout << aircraftList_.at(i);
    }
}
```

Could i get some help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is an easier way to iterate the vector.

```
void ListAllAircraft(std::vector<Aircraft> &aircraftList_)
{
    for (auto const &aircraft : aircraftList_)
    {
        std::cout << aircraft;
    }
}
```

Using `sizeof` is wrong. The [sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) queries size of the object in memory. This would include all the internal members of your specific implementation of std::vector. To query an instance of an std::vector for the number of elements it stores, you use [std::vector::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

For stream output to work though, you need to have a [stream insertion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) defined for your Aircraft class. Otherwise the compiler cannot know what you want it to print when you call `std::cout << aircraft;`.
How this insertion operator should look totally depends on your Aircraft class and what you want to be printed for each aircraft. It could be something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Aircraft& aircraft)
{
    stream << aircraft.name 
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: sigy, i just tried that but im getting the same error, "No operator matches these operands, operand types are std::ostream << aircraft" –

Comment: I took the liberty of slightly editing your good answer (+1), hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

none of your function are returning a std::vector

It seems they return void. This code can not compile